# How to find date and time coming in between two given date and time in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have two date and time in PHP:

```
$date1 = 2014-07-19 13:00
$date2 = 2014-07-20 13:00
```

What I want is an `array of date and time` come in between the two date and time, including the given dates also.

Like **2014-07-19 13:00, 2014-07-19 14:00, 2014-07-19 15:00, ... 2014-07-20 11:00, 2014-07-20 12:00, 2014-07-20 13:00**

When I searched, I found the code to get the dates in between two dates. But it doesn't include time. I want time as well.

Comment: "When I searched, I found the code to get the dates in between two dates. But it doesn't include time. I want time as well." Did you consider writing your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
<?php

$date1 = date_create('2014-07-19 13:00');
$date2 = date_create('2014-07-20 13:00');
$newArr = array();
// if start date is to be included then use
$newArr[] = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

while($date1 < $date2) {
    $date1 = date_add($date1,date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 hour'));
    $newArr[] = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

and [here](http://3v4l.org/nOQuK#v530) is the fiddle with demonstration

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-07-19 13:00:00
    [1] => 2014-07-19 14:00:00
    [2] => 2014-07-19 15:00:00
    [3] => 2014-07-19 16:00:00
    [4] => 2014-07-19 17:00:00
    [5] => 2014-07-19 18:00:00
    [6] => 2014-07-19 19:00:00
    [7] => 2014-07-19 20:00:00
    [8] => 2014-07-19 21:00:00
    [9] => 2014-07-19 22:00:00
    [10] => 2014-07-19 23:00:00
    [11] => 2014-07-20 00:00:00
    [12] => 2014-07-20 01:00:00
    [13] => 2014-07-20 02:00:00
    [14] => 2014-07-20 03:00:00
    [15] => 2014-07-20 04:00:00
    [16] => 2014-07-20 05:00:00
    [17] => 2014-07-20 06:00:00
    [18] => 2014-07-20 07:00:00
    [19] => 2014-07-20 08:00:00
    [20] => 2014-07-20 09:00:00
    [21] => 2014-07-20 10:00:00
    [22] => 2014-07-20 11:00:00
    [23] => 2014-07-20 12:00:00
    [24] => 2014-07-20 13:00:00
)
```

Comment: Doesn't include first date

Comment: This is working fine. But I want my start date time and end date time to be included in the array. 
Here datetime1  is not included and an extra date time is added towards the end.

Comment: Adding $newArr[] = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); before the while loop and changing the loop while($date1 < $date2) like this will resolve my issue.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham, I have modified the code as per your requirement. Lemme know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DatePeriod`

```
$daterange = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2014-07-19 13:00'), 
    new DateInterval('PT1H'), 
    new DateTime('2014-07-20 13:00')
);

//if you just need to iterate
foreach($daterange as $date) {
   print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";
}

//if you need an actual array
$dateArray = iterator_to_array($daterange);
print_r($dateArray);
```

Comment: You don't need the foreach loop here `$dateArray = iterator_to_array($daterange);` will do the same job. http://php.net/iterator_to_array

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [**range()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$date1 = '2014-07-19 13:00';
$date2 = '2014-07-20 13:00';

$date_range = range(strtotime($date1), strtotime($date2), 3600);

foreach ($date_range as $k=>$a) 
    $date_range[$k] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);

print_r($date_range);
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/j8jFli)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdate = $date1;
$dates = array();
$dates[] = $next;
while(strtotime($newdate) < strtotime($date2))
{
   // on each iteration, add 1 hour to previous timestamp
   $next = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($newdate.' +1 hour'));
   $dates[] = $next;
   $newdate = $next;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dates);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QI7GXP)

Comment: Doesn't include first date

Comment: Good point...missed it out somehow..now added

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date1 = '2014-07-19 13:00';
$date2 = '2014-07-20 13:00';

$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
$diff_seconds = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
$diff_hours    = ceil($diff_seconds/3600);

for($i= 0 ; $i < $diff_hours; $i++){
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d H:i', $timestamp1 + ($i *3600));
}
```